# Turn signal not returning to neutral

Tags: mazda, turn-signal

I am considering buying a 2005 Mazda 3i. One of the problems with the car is that, when turning right, the turn signal does not return to neutral on its own, you have to do it manually.

What part does this problem correspond to? 
How costly of a repair would it be?

My guess is that it can't be much, also if I don't have any experience fixing cars, but I'm generally smart enough to figure things out, would this be a repair I could do my self?

thanks

Comment: [Same question for a Chevy Equinox](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1948/is-it-possible-or-practical-to-repair-a-turn-signal-cancel-switch-instead-of-r?rq=1) and [a Malibu](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/889/how-to-i-stop-the-never-ending-turn-signal?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your blinker module is broken. This is on the left side behind the steering wheel. There is some mechanical part connected to the steering wheel. If you turn blinker right, some little tooth came out of this module. Then if you turn the wheel back, it touch the tooth of the steering wheel and release to blinker to neutral. Maybe if you build up this module, you will see, what is wrong. The new on will cost something about 120 Euro in Germany.